# jquery validation plugin- change border color + no text

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Is there anyway I can change the border-color to red on an error rather and get rid of the text? That's pretty much the only error I want to display, and it would disappear once the input/textarea becomes focused.

```
<div id="contact-form">
            <form method="get" id="contacts">
                <div class="contact-controls">
                    <label class="contact-label" for="name-input">NAME</label>
                    <div class="input-wrapper">
                        <input type="text" name="contact-name" id="name-input" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-controls">
                    <label class="contact-label" for="email-input">EMAIL</label>
                    <div class="input-wrapper">
                        <input type="text" name="contact-email" id="email-input" placeholder="Your Email" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-controls">
                    <label class="contact-label" for="message-input">MESSAGE</label>
                    <div class="input-wrapper">
                        <textarea name="contact-message" id="message-input" rows="15" placeholder="Hi there&#33;" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-controls">
                    <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">  
                    <button type="submit" class="contact-button">Send</button>  
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: we would need to see your current validation script that is "getting rid of the text"

Comment: Ah, I don't have it yet, I'm wondering if there is a way, or is these is another plugin that can do what I am looking for

Comment: Yes, there is an easy way.  See my answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do the following:

1)  Set the `errorPlacement` callback function to `return false` to suppress the error message text.

2)  Modify the CSS for the plugin's `.error` & `.valid` `class`'s to show colored borders, or whatever, around the element.  By default, the plugin already automatically applies and removes these two `class`'s, so there's no special plugin options to set for this.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/8vQFd/**

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // your rules and options,
        errorPlacement: function(){
            return false;  // suppresses error message text
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Sweet, this is pretty much perfect. Question: on page load my first input field is already showing an error (.error { border: 1px red solid}); how can I make it so it only flags an error once the user enters incorrect characters?

Comment: @vytfla, Just follow my jsfiddle which already does what you want.  Since I can't see your `.validate()` function, I'm not sure how that's happening.  Can you modify my jsFiddle to show this issue?

Comment: @vytfla, that's just [my original jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vQFd/) and no errors are highlighted on load.  You have to click the "update" or "fork" button to save any changes.

Comment: @vytfla,  So just remove `class="error"` from the element.  The plugin will put it back automatically when there's an error.  Also see my comments in the JS:  http://jsfiddle.net/RaPUY/2/

Comment: Thanks, I thought I took that out. I don't understand your comments- #myform -> #myForm and why did you add the comment slashes at the end?

Comment: @vytfla, I was simply trying to tell you that you misspelled the `#myForm` selector as `#myform`, and you left out the closing brackets, `})`.

Comment: @Sparky- Oh, wow, thanks. I thought I had like triple checked that.

Answer (score 1):

No Jquery No Add other/ Modify Any Functionality Just Add Css

```
input[class="error"]{border:1px solid #f00 !important;} input[class="form control error"]{border:1px solid #f00 !important;} .error p{color:#f00 !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a CSS class named **.input-validation-error** which is added to the input element by jQuery validation plugin when a validation rule is broken.

```css
.input-validation-error {
    border: solid 1px #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple css based method would be something like the following:

```
input.error{border: 1px solid red;}
```

You'll probably want to expand on this but its a good starting point.

Comment: Please make more obvious the additional insight this post contributes in comparison to existing posts which seem to be similar. What is the relevant difference? Which benefit does it have? What is the functional difference which harvests that benefit?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Notably, it's unclear what this offers relative to [@Mohammed Sakhidel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50680039/3025856) from three years ago, which provides a similar border, but based on jQuery Validation's specific `input-validation-error` class, or [@user2650063's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46727337/3025856) from four years ago, which provides a selector for `input.error`, but also provides some extended selectors to address other cases. Each cover your basic proposal, using exclusively CSS.

Answer (score -1):

You could add a class to your input / textareas that would add a red border

*I called it .error*

```
input:focus,textarea:focus{
outline: none !important;
}

input.error, textarea.error{
outline:red groove thin;
}
```

Then use jquery to go and find the input /textareas with the class '.error' and empty set the value of it to blank.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact-form').find('.error').val(' ');
});
```

[Jsfiddle V1](http://jsfiddle.net/kx5tg/)

**Updated**

Example of JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact-form').find('.error').val(' ');
    $('input, textarea').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('error').val('');
   });

    var name = $('#name-input').val();

    if(name == ''){
      $('#name-input').addClass('error');   
    }
   });
```

CSS

```
 input:focus,textarea:focus{
  border-color: initial;
 }

 input.error, textarea.error{
  border:1px solid red;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="contact-form">
        <form method="get" id="contacts">
            <div class="contact-controls">
                <label class="contact-label" for="name-input">NAME</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <input type="text" name="contact-name" id="name-input" placeholder="Your Name" value="" class="" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-controls">
                <label class="contact-label" for="email-input">EMAIL</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <input type="email" name="contact-email" id="email-input" placeholder="Your Email" value="" class="" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-controls">
                <label class="contact-label" for="message-input">MESSAGE</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <textarea name="contact-message" id="message-input" rows="15" placeholder="Hi there&#33;" class="" required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-controls">
                <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">  
                <button type="submit" class="contact-button">Send</button>  
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

[JSfiddle V2](http://jsfiddle.net/3listone/kx5tg/1/)

Comment: Your jsfiddle has the email/message borders already red; I'm looking for them to change to red once the user presses send when the fields are empty.

Comment: Which ever language you are using to process you data if there is an error add the class 'error' to the input box, (you could also set the value that way as well)

Comment: I think you totally missed the point.  The OP is using the jQuery Validate plugin which already has various built-in callback options for doing all this.